# saving data in python using csv

Tags: python, csv

I wanna write this code that saves a link with a description (simple)

```
from csv import *
from os import system

Data = "C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\Data.csv"
row = []

def loading(Data):
    x = []
    r = ''
    with open(Data,'r') as DFr:
        Read = reader(DFr)
        a = next(Read) #Giving first row which is a field
        for rows in Read:
            x.append(rows)
    for objs in x:
        for v in objs:
            r = r + v
        r = r + '  '
    return r

def saving(Data,row):
    with open(Data,'w') as DFr:
        writeDT = writer(DFr)
        writeDT.writerow(["Link","Description"])
        writeDT.writerows(row)
    return

system("cls")
while True:
    x = input("cammand (save/load/exit) : ").lower()
    if  x == "save":
        Input = input("link: ")
        Input2 = input("description: ")
        saving(Data,[[Input],[Input2]])
        pass
    elif x == "load":
        print('\n',loading(Data),'\n')
    elif x == "exit":
        quit()
```

load function show all saved link and description.This code only saves last entered data.But I want to save all entered data.

1. How to save all datas?
2. Do you know better way to saving datas?

I would appreciate it if you help me  :)

Comment: in saving. use the 'a+' flag to append to the file. 'w' will just overwrite the file.

Comment: Let's be honest.  In this particular case, it would be better for you to use a text editor to create the file.  Your app is not a better way to enter the data.  You can't go back and fix your errors.

Comment: And you don't want `[[Input],[Input2]]`.  That's a list of lists.  Just `[Input,Input2]` will do.